# INCREMENTAR EL VALOR DE UNA VARIABLE PHP PRESIONANDO UN BOTON TIPO SUBMIT

Tags: php, html

- Disculpen tengo un formulario html e hice un reporte en pdf donde tengo una variable PHP llamada Numero. Quisiera saber como se puede hacer para que al momento que presione un boton en mi formulario html en mi otro archivo php donde tengo el pdf que hice la variable que muestro se vaya incrementando n veces.
  ejemplo: presiono mi boton en mi HTML en mi pdf se muestre Numero: 10001, vuelvo presionar mi boton y en mi pdf se muestre Numero: 10002 y asì sucesivamente.

Por dar un ejemplo tengo el siguiente Codigo:

+

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>
 
<?php
if (isset($_POST['genera_do'])){
//Incrementamos el valor
$contador = 1000;
$conta = $_POST["conta"]+1;

}
else{
//Valor inicial
$conta = 1;
}
?>
 
...
 
<form name="f1" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td style="font-size: 10px; text-align: center;border: 1px solid black;">
<input type="text" name="conta" value="<?php echo $conta?>">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  name="genera_do"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf"></i> Reporte</button>
</form>
 
...
 
</body>
</html>
```

- El codigo que muestro me funciona pero solo me incrementa de 1 en 1, es decir presiono mi boton y me imprime 1, vuelvo a presionar y me imprime 2 quisiera que empezara a contar desde el 1000, que cuando presione me muestre 1002 y asi sucesivamente

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hMt1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Podrías guardar el valor de tus visitas en un archivo.
De esa manera siempre se incrementarán tus visitas.
Esta función podrías adaptarla a tu código.

```
<?php
   function contarvisitas() {
        $archivo = "contadorvisitas.txt";
        $f = fopen($archivo, "r"); 
        if($f) {
            $contador = fread($f, filesize($archivo));
            $contador = $contador + 1; 
            fclose($f);
        }
        $f = fopen($archivo, "w+");
        if($f) {
            fwrite($f, $contador);
            fclose($f);
        }
        return $contador;
    }
    echo contarvisitas();
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias voy a probar, pero por ejemplo si quisiera que al volver a abrir el archivo no se reinicie si no que empiece a contar de nuevo desde el ultimo numero que genero, no se si habria que registrar informacion en la base de datos?

Comment: Este código hace eso. Prueba y verás que el correlativo no se pierde.